# Why is heat flux a vector?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, vectors

If heat flux is the rate of flow of a scalar (energy) per unit area per unit time at a point then how can it be a vector quantity? Is it because the unit area the energy is divided can be represented by a vector?
I have been told I should think about what it would mean to add two fluxes together and why they might add vectorially, but I do not see how that could help me...
Thanks!

Comment: The flux goes in some direction(s), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flux of heat has direction, not only magnitude. So this is why it's a vector. The unit area is represented by a unit vector that indicates the direction of the flow.

Think about the Fourier's law: $\vec{J} = - k\nabla T$. The flux is determined by the gradient of a scalar function, so it's a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Flux is in a direction relative to a normal to the surface area. Traditionally, the normal points outward from the control volume that is bounded by the area. Flux into the control volume is negative (opposing the normal) while the temperature gradient is positive (cold to hot as referenced by the direction of the normal to the area). Flux out of the control volume is positive (in the same direction as the normal) while the temperature gradient is negative (hot to cold as referenced by the direction of the normal to the area). Hence we have the negative sign in the Fourier law for heat flux to temperature gradient.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of subtleties that I'd like to supplement.

First of all, there is a potential confusion between a (1) "flux" as an integrated amount of energy passing through some pre-specified surface and a (2) "flux density" as an continuous distribution that you are supposed to integrate. Usually the "density" bit is implied by context and not stressed in physics discussions.

Secondly. If you want to get deeper in formal mathematics of it, then we'll need to use the language of [differential geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry). And, as it turns out, formally flux density is not a vector. Flux density is something that you should be able to integrate over an oriented 2d surface. In the language of differential geometry, these are called [differential 2-forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form).

Typically - in the flat 3d space, that is - there is a usual [Hodge start isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Three_dimensions) between 2-forms and "normal" 3d vectors. But in general case of curved manifolds with non-trivial metric the distinction can be important.